# Python Google Photos API List Items in Album

Tags: python, google-api, google-photos-api

I am having trouble extending the API calls required to list album ids to be able to list the items contained in the album.  An example of what I have done to retrieve album ids appears below.  Beyond that example, I include my attempt to extend this script to be able to list the items contained in a specific album.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'
store = file.storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

hasNextPageToken = False
nextPageToken = ""

results = service.albums().list(pageSize=10).execute()

if 'nextPageToken' in results:
    hasNextPageToken = True
    nextPageToken = results['nextPageToken']
    for album in results['albums']:
        albumId = album['id']
        print(albumId)
```

Now, for the code that I am attempting to modify from the example above to be able to list the items in a given album defined by `albumId`:

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'
store = file.storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

hasNextPageToken = False
nextPageToken = ""
albumId = [albumIdFromPreviousStep]
results = service.mediaItems().search(pageSize=10,albumId=albumId).execute()
```

When I attempt to print the `results`, I receive an error about receiving an unexpected keyword argument, `albumId`.

The api call is formatted differently for search, it is `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search`

Is the error stemming from the : `mediaItems:search` which invalidates the variable in Python?  Or is it related to the fact that the search call is a POST rather than a GET?  Or, something else?

Answer (score 1):

The `mediaitems:search` requires a `JSON`-structured body of parameters in order to restrict the returned items to a specific albumId.

Modifying the second part of the code from the original post gives the desired result.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly'
store = file.storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

hasNextPageToken = False
nextPageToken = ""
body = {
    "albumId": [AlbumId],
    "pageSize": 10
    }
results = service.mediaItems().search(body=body).execute()
print(results)
```

Now, collecting the data for all the other items requires incorporating the `nextPageToken` and looping through the results.

Answer (score 0):

i cant see anywhere you defined albumId in your modified code

```
results = service.mediaItems().search(pageSize=10,**albumId=albumId**).execute()
```

the code you copied from clearly defines it

```
for album in results['albums']:
    albumId = album['id']
    print(albumId)
```

Comment: you're right - I missed that, the original will be updated soon.  Thanks for the catch

Comment: you'll probably make two calls, one to grab the id and the second to loop through

Comment: I agree - I am seeking help on the 2nd call.  It employs a different service from the one used to list album ids and I believe I am not setting that service correctly.